# pass slider value to subview

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I have a `UISlider` placed in my main view and I have added a subview `UIView` (via interface builder) that I have associated with its own class `SecondView`. I need to pass the value of the slider to my sub view to move a point in the sub view when the slider changes.

*I have made changes to the original code and the the below paragraph no longer is accurate. I used used the suggested changes offered by @MatthiasBauch.*

<strike>I thought it would be simple a matter of sharing an iVar between the two. I created an iVar `myPoint` using `@property` (if this is still considered an iVar) in my `ViewController` interface, set `myPoint = sliderValue.value` in my `ViewController` implementation in the `IBAction` for when the slider value changes. Then in my `SecondView` implementation I `#import "ViewController.h"` then call my call my iVar in my `SecondView` implementation but the way I have done it it only returns `nil` or `0` instead of the slider value.</strike>

I don't want to use global variables.

I have looked at other post that seem to be asking a similar question but I'm still missing the concept, I guess. My code is below.

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondView.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    SecondView *secondView; // Do I need this with secondView declared as a @property below?
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) SecondView *secondView;

- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *sliderValue;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *myView;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondView.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize sliderValue, myLabel, myView, secondView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    secondView.thePoint = 50;
    NSLog(@"%f", secondView.thePoint); // This is retuning a zero
}

- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender
{
    secondView.thePoint = sliderValue.value;
    myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", sliderValue.value];
    [secondView setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

**SecondView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondView : UIView

@property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat thePoint;

@end
```

**SecondView.m**

```
#import "SecondView.h"

@implementation SecondView

@synthesize thePoint;

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    float aPoint = thePoint;
    NSLog(@"%f", aPoint); // this is retuning 0.000000
    UIBezierPath *point = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(aPoint, 100, 4, 4)];
    [point fill];
}

@end
```

Comment: 1. No need to apologize ;-) 2. It makes your question more readable if you omit all methods that you didn't implemented yourself. There is really no need to post the default implementation of `initWithFrame:` or `didReceiveMemoryWarning`.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch, the code is updated. What'd I miss?

Comment: you probably haven't created (or connected in interface builder)  `secondView`. Add `NSParameterAssert(secondView);` in your viewDidLoad. If this assert fails (i.e. the app crashes at this line) it means `secondView` is nil because it wasn't connected in Interface Builder and you haven't created it yourself.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch, yes that is apparently my problem. How do I connect it in interface builder? Is it not an IBOutlet connected to my UIView? Am I way off base with this?

Comment: @MatthiasBauch, I placed a UIView in interface builder and changed the custom class of my UIView to secondView. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: @MatthiasBauch OK, I figured out my problem... I originally had my IBOutlet type set as UIView instead of SecondView. Once I corrected my type everything works as it should. FYI... setNeedsDisplay is necessary as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell the view where to draw and don't ask the (newly allocated) viewController where to draw.

You are allocating a new viewController, this viewController of course does not know the value you set in the viewController where you actually changed the slider.
This won't work. Those two viewControllers are not the same instance. They share the same class, but that's it. Values from one viewController instance don't magically appear in a second instance.

Instead you should set a point property of the secondary view in your slider action.

Something like this:

Add a float @property to your view

```
@interface SecondView : UIView
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat point;
@end
```

to draw use that point and not the initial value from a new ViewController instance.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    float aPoint = self.point;

    UIBezierPath *point = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(aPoint, 100, 4, 4)];
    [point fill];
}
```

and set the point property of the secondary view in the slider action

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender
{
    secondView.point = sliderValue.value;
    [secondView setNeedsDisplay];         // you might be able to omit that

    myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", myPoint];
}
```

Comment: I like this approach and I used the code you provided but I must be missing something because it still keeps retuning a zero. I will update my code above to reflect my current code.

Answer (score -1):

Your ViewController has a property called `@myView` which points to the instance of SecondView created by the runtime.

So, your ViewController's implementation could call the `drawRect:` method on `myView` and pass in the relevant coordinates.

Here's some pseudo code for your ViewController.

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender
{
    myPoint = sliderValue.value;
    myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", myPoint];

    [myView drawRect:CGRectMake(myPoint, 100, 4, 4)];
}
```

Note however that in your ViewController, `myView` is just a UIView, not a SecondView. You have a few choices on how to resolve this. The cleanest way is probably to remove the `#import ViewController.h` from SecondView and instead do the opposite. That is, have ViewController do an `#import SecondView.h`, then promote `myView` to a SecondView.

If that doesn't work for some reason (for example, if XCode demands that it remain strictly a UIView), you can still upcast the `myView` property at runtime like this:

```
    [(*SecondView)myView drawRect:CGRectMake(myPoint, 100, 4, 4)];
```

Alternatively, you could point your slider's action at myView like the answer to this question does for a button: [subclass UIView actions in viewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266167/subclass-uiview-actions-in-viewcontroller)

As usual in programming, there are several possible solutions. It's up to you to pick the best one for you. Good luck!

Comment: [You should never call `drawRect:` directly.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCDGJHF) The rect parameter of `drawRect:` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: I have previously connected my slider to UIView and this works; however, my slider will eventually control a pretty complicated math problem and I don't want to a) duplicate code and b) add the additional demand on the memory and device.